# Issue with EntityType Querybuilder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5.4

> So my problem is that whenever im sumbitting my form after filling in it gives me an error `Expected argument of type "string", "App\Entity\User" given at property path "naamklant".` i've used every possible method and im trying to solve this issue.

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Dagrooster;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class DagroosterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('klant', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Bedrijfsnaam',
            ])
            ->add('kamer', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Kamer 1' => 1,
                    'Kamer 2' => 2,
                    'Kamer 3' => 3,
                ]
            ])
            ->add('naamklant', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => User::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.roles LIKE :role')
                        ->setParameter('role', '%ROLE_MEMBER%');
                },
                'choice_label' => function($name){
                    return $name->getFname();
                },
                ))

            ->add('onderwerp', TextType::class)
            ->add('datum', DateTimeType::class)
            ->add('sumbit', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Dagrooster::class,
            'ROLE_MEMBER' => 0
        ]);
    }
}
```

I've added querybuilder to try out to only choose role_members and nothing else but it still gives me the same error.

```
>add('naamklant', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => User::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.roles LIKE :role')
                        ->setParameter('role', '%ROLE_MEMBER%');
                },
                'choice_label' => function($name){
                    return $name->getFname();
                },
                ))
```

user entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`user`')]
#[UniqueEntity(fields: ['email'], message: 'There is already an account with this email')]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     */
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $fname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $lname = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'User', targetEntity: Ziekmelding::class)]
    private Collection $ziekmeldings;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'User', targetEntity: Dagrooster::class)]
    private Collection $dagroosters;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ziekmeldings = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->dagroosters = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): static
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_EMPLOYEE';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): static
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): static
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials(): void
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getFname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->fname;
    }

    public function setFname(string $fname): static
    {
        $this->fname = $fname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lname;
    }

    public function setLname(string $lname): static
    {
        $this->lname = $lname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Ziekmelding>
     */
    public function getZiekmeldings(): Collection
    {
        return $this->ziekmeldings;
    }

    public function addZiekmelding(Ziekmelding $ziekmelding): static
    {
        if (!$this->ziekmeldings->contains($ziekmelding)) {
            $this->ziekmeldings->add($ziekmelding);
            $ziekmelding->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeZiekmelding(Ziekmelding $ziekmelding): static
    {
        if ($this->ziekmeldings->removeElement($ziekmelding)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($ziekmelding->getUser() === $this) {
                $ziekmelding->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Dagrooster>
     */
    public function getDagroosters(): Collection
    {
        return $this->dagroosters;
    }

    public function addDagrooster(Dagrooster $dagrooster): static
    {
        if (!$this->dagroosters->contains($dagrooster)) {
            $this->dagroosters->add($dagrooster);
            $dagrooster->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDagrooster(Dagrooster $dagrooster): static
    {
        if ($this->dagroosters->removeElement($dagrooster)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($dagrooster->getUser() === $this) {
                $dagrooster->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

dagrooster entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\DagroosterRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: DagroosterRepository::class)]
class Dagrooster
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $klant = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $kamer = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $naamklant = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $onderwerp = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $datum = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'dagroosters')]
    private ?User $User = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getKlant(): ?string
    {
        return $this->klant;
    }

    public function setKlant(string $klant): static
    {
        $this->klant = $klant;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getKamer(): ?string
    {
        return $this->kamer;
    }

    public function setKamer(string $kamer): static
    {
        $this->kamer = $kamer;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNaamklant(): ?string
    {
        return $this->naamklant;
    }

    public function setNaamklant(string $naamklant): static
    {
        $this->naamklant = $naamklant;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOnderwerp(): ?string
    {
        return $this->onderwerp;
    }

    public function setOnderwerp(string $onderwerp): static
    {
        $this->onderwerp = $onderwerp;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatum(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->datum;
    }

    public function setDatum(\DateTimeInterface $datum): static
    {
        $this->datum = $datum;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->User;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $User): static
    {
        $this->User = $User;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, your setting your widget to an `EntityType`.
So, after resolution, your submitted value will be an instance of `User` for the property `naamklant`.
Then Symfony will try to set the properties of the underlying object, in this case your entity `Dagrooster`. It will check of a setter (`setNaamklant()`) an  call it with the submitted value (a `User` instance).
As the method is expecting a `string` and not a `User` you get this error message.
The way to solve it, is either by changing the `$naamklant` property in the `Dagrooster` from `string` to `User` or by changing the property `naamKlant` to `User` in the form.

```php
// In the entity replace this
#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
private ?string $naamklant = null;
// by
#[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: User::class)]
private ?User $naamklant = null

// ------ OR ------

// In the form, replace
->add('naamklant', EntityType::class, ...)
// by
->add('User', EntityType::class, ...)
```

->add('naamklant', EntityType::class

Comment: Instead of changing the database, you can also use a `DataTransformer` which can extract information from the User Entity and save it like that. However, there seem to be some relation between the two, so maybe a relation would be better.

Comment: So i've done what you told me to do. and it seems like another problem occured after that.
Expected argument of type "?App\Entity\User", "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given at property path "user".

Comment: Did you set the option multiple in the form for the user? If so, you should remove it.

Comment: no i haven't done that. @Vincent

Comment: Can you show the `user` declaration in your form?

Comment: ])
            ->add('naamklant', EntityType::class, [
                "query_builder" => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder("u")
                        ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles ')
                        ->setParameter('roles', '%"ROLE_MEMBER"%');
                },
                'class' => User::class,
                'choice_label' => function (User $user): string {
                    return $user->getFname();
                },

Comment: @bulent This is the declaration of the `naamklant` property. It will be mapped on the property with the same name in the entity. I need to see the `user` property from the form `->add('user', ...)`